# Average maximum MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select the average of the high score for 2-3 players but im not sure how to go about this.

Table `Match` has (id, player, score)

I would like to get the maximum score for each specified player (by id) and then calculate the average of these returned scores.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is at least 2 different interpretations of the goal described. Show some example - source data and desired output which you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Match(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, score integer);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Match VALUES(1,'10');
INSERT INTO Match VALUES(2,'20');
INSERT INTO Match VALUES(3,'60');
INSERT INTO Match VALUES(4,'100');
INSERT INTO Match VALUES(5,'80');
COMMIT;


select m.*,
       (select sum(score)
        from (select score
              from Match s
              where s.id = s.id
              order by score desc
              limit 3
             ) s2
       ) as summax3
from Match m
```

Answer (score -1):

The following query is going to return the highest score of each player:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT `match`.id, `match`.score
    FROM `match`
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS high_scores
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY score DESC
```

And for getting the average:

```
SELECT AVG(score) AS average
FROM
    (
    SELECT `match`.id, `match`.score
    FROM `match`
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS high_scores
```